# Caffe Installation Issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04, deep-learning, caffe

I successfully installed caffe on my dual-boot laptop (GTX 860M, Windows 7 + Ubuntu 14.04.2). All the tests were successfully passed. When I **restarted**, however, the ubuntu got stuck on the opening screen (the one with ubuntu logo and **five red dots**). Don't know what to do with it.

Has anyone run into the same issue before? I reckon something is wrong with graphic card driver booting. I installed newest CUDA 7 Toolkit with nvidia drivers built inside. Since all tests were passed before I restarted, it seems that the driver would work once successfully booted.

the stuck screen is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRtEF.jpg

Comment: Maybe try on askubuntu.com or superuser.com

Comment: Please mark @maarten-bamelis's answer as correct, since I think it solves the problem nicely.

Comment: Try editing the grub entry. When the grub menu comes up, press `e`. Find the line which has `quiet splash` and type in `nomodeset=0` Works for some laptops

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when trying to install Caffe on my system. The steps below worked for me, but it has at least one known issue (documented below).

I'm not sure what precisely caused this problem, but it surely has something to do with the Nvidia Driver and Cuda Toolkit installation and is **not caused by Caffe**.

After completing the steps below, I've been able to successfully install Caffe on my system with the following tutorials and guides:

- [Official Install Guide](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html)
- [Github Install Guide](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM)

---

### Update

Recently, I had the exact same problem trying to **make Cuda 7.5 work on Ubuntu 14.04;** this approach also solved that problem. Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i7-4700MQ (4x 2.40 GHz with Hyperthreading)
- GPU: NVidia GT 940M
- RAM: 8 GB
- HDD: 52.7 GB (of which 6.7 GB used after installation)

---

## INSTALL NVIDIA DRIVER AND CUDA ON UBUNTU 14.04

Source: [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246526](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246526)

**!! Known Issues !!**

- After the system has been suspended (or hibernated, not confirmed), all applications using the Nvidia Driver and Cuda 6.5 Toolkit will freeze. When this happens, the command `sudo shutdown -r now` will print the reboot message but nothing will happen.

**Executed and tested on a fresh 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 install with the following hardware specifications:**

- CPU: Intel Core i5-2410m (2x 2.30 GHz with Hyperthreading)
- GPU: NVidia GT 540M
- RAM: 6 GB
- HDD: 52.7 GB (of which 8.6 GB used after installation)

**The following command was executed before installation:**

```
sudo apt-get -y build-essential vim git llvm clang
```

**The following steps resulted in a stable system with the latest Nvidia Driver and Cuda 6.5 Toolkit installed:**

1. Remove all traces of previous/legacy Nvidia Drivers and Cuda Toolkits or perform a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install.
2. Download the latest Nvidia Driver .run file for Ubuntu 14.04 and your system specifications to the `~/Downloads` directory.
   e.g.: `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run`
3. Download the latest Cuda 6.5 Toolkit .run file for Ubuntu 14.04 and your system specifications to the `~/Downloads` directory.
   e.g.: `cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run`
4. Blacklist the 'nouveau' Driver by appending the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (nouveau is a free open-source driver for Nvidia cards, it is the default for Ubuntu 14.04):

   `blacklist nouveau`
   `options nouveau modeset=0`
5. Reboot the system, do **NOT** log in but drop to the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
6. Kill lightdm (replace 'lightdm' with your own Display Manager if you have changed it, lightdm is the default for Ubuntu 14.04):

   `sudo service lightdm stop`

***The next step is critical, make sure to check twice before continuing!***

7. Run the Nvidia Driver installer with the `--no-opengl-files` option (the option prevents OpenGL files from being overwritten; without this option, Unity would not function properly and the screen would freeze after login):

   `sudo chmod +x ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x68_64-346.35.run`
   `sudo ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x68_64-346.35.run --no-opengl-files`
8. Accept the EULA and acknowledge all further warnings but **deny** to install anything extra.
9. Reboot and login to the desktop, verify with the 'Additional Drivers' (System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers) utility that the manually installed driver is in use.
10. Open a terminal and install the Cuda 6.5 Toolkit:

    `sudo chmod +x ~/Downloads/cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run`
    `sudo ~/Downloads/cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run`
11. Accept the EULA, do **NOT** install the driver, install the Toolkit and the Examples (if you want to), leave all default directories in place.
12. Add the Cuda 6.5 Toolkit environment variables by appending the following lines to `~/.bashrc`:

    `# For 32-bit systems, append these:`
    `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin`
    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib`

    `# For 64-bit systems, append these:`
    `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin`
    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64`

The Nvidia Driver and Cuda 6.5 Toolkit should now be correctly installed.

**Optional:** confirm your Nvidia Driver and Cuda 6.5 Toolkit installation.

13. Confirm the Nvidia Driver installation by running the following command:

    `nvidia-smi`
14. Confirm the Cuda Compiler installation by running the following command:

    `nvcc -V`
15. Confirm everything works by building and running the optionally installed Cuda Examples: (build-essential is required to use 'make')

    `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`
    `cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_SAMPLES/1_Utilities/deviceQuery`
    `make`
    `./deviceQuery`
    `cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-6.5_SAMPLES/1_Utilities/bandwidthTest`
    `make`
    `./bandwidthTest`

Comment: Amazing answer, solved my long standing headache on the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to 'Remove all traces of previous/legacy Nvidia Drivers and Cuda Toolkits'

Comment: @kli_nlpr Unless you are experiencing problems with graphics drivers, I would recommend you simply skip that step. To revert to the default driver for Ubuntu (which is Nouveau), you can use the Additional Drivers utility (System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers) to select it or take a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/476659

Comment: @Maarten Bamelis  I use sudo /usr/local/cuda/bin/uninstall_cuda_7.5.pl and sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall to uninstall nvidia driver and cuda. Then I follow your steps and reinstall nvidia driver and cuda for caffe on Ubuntu 14.04 successfully, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to caffe.

The problem is that the nVidia driver that is installed from the ubuntu software center does not support your card.

Uninstall any nvidia package (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`) and install the latest driver version from the nvidia website.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change the cuda 7.5 ubuntu 15.04 version. I try it on the ubuntu 14.04, it solves this problem. And when I install cuda 7.5 ubuntu 14.04 version on ubuntu 14.04 I countered the exactly problem.